# Finding source of node.js's memory leak - buffer size growing out of control?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks

I'm getting some traffic to a server of mine and I'm not sure how to deal with this problem.
I've added the [nodetime](http://nodetime.com) to my app, and here's the result of a heap snapshot. Retainers > Other is up to 88% from 78% (in a matter of a couple of minutes)

[image]

Overall system's free memory decrease:

[image]

It's slow, but definitely happens. The jump up around 21:20 is when I restarted the server.

The server itself is basically collecting logs: it saves incoming requests to MongoDB, reads from MongoDB once and occasionally sets Redis key. In other words, it's a pretty simple set-up.

How do I track down what what this buffer is? In addition, is there a list somewhere of basic do-not's that can cause this type of issue?

I should also mention that running stress tests with `ab` causes the server to consume proportionately more memory, so it's definitely a node.js issue and likely not another process that's eating up the memory.

Would it be helpful to dig through the code and rename as many anonymous functions as possible?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but are you closing the MongoDB connections properly?

Comment: Does the mongoDB connection need to be opened and closed around each request? I have a mongo connection object defined on server start which is then used all around the app. Is  this not the right way to do it?

Comment: No that's fine. You can connect once and reuse, I just wanted to check you weren't connecting for each request which I have seen before.